# SQL - Using GROUP BY and MIN COUNT to return the least counted variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by, min

I'm having trouble using `GROUP BY`, `MAX`, and `COUNT`.

I have 3 tables, t1, t2, t3 with nutrition data.

- t1 contains `userid`
- t2 contains `food` and the `type` of food. (fruit, meat, etc)
- t3 records each time userid eats food, so `userid`, `food`

How do you write a (Postgres) query that returns only the `userid` and the **least** eaten `type` of food?

I keep getting stuck on `GROUP BY` because of aggregations that create combinations of each type of food. Any hints on how I should approach this?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result when you want sql query, and show us what you have tried as possible as you can.

Comment: t4 contains the solution.

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel, this is a typical [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query (which have [plenty of solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group?sort=votes)), just reverse the operators to find the *least*, instead of the *greatest*.

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid, max(c_type) as MaxType
From (Select userid, count(type) as c_type 
from t1 inner join t3 on t1.userid = t3.userid
        inner join t2 on t2.food = t3.food
group by userid) as T
group by userid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the least often eaten food type for each user, first count occurrences by user AND type, then you need to use a rank function to determine which of those food types has the lowest count. I'm not going to bother writing out all the joins, but this pseudocode should help:

```
select user_id, type, type_total
from ( select user_id, type, type_total,
       rank(type_total) over (partition by user_id, type order by type_total) rn
       from ( select user_id, type, count(t3 identifier) type_total
              from [insert all the tables and joins here]
              group by user_id, type ) x
       ) y
where y.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This method uses the ROW_NUMBER window function with an ascending sort on the count of food items eaten grouped by the type to determine the least eaten. If there is a tie, a random one of the least types will be selected. Using RANK like in @htf's solution posted will return all ties.

```
select userid, type from (
    select t3.userid, t2.type, count(*) as eaten,
        row_number() over(partition by t3.userid order by count(t3.food) asc) AS r
    from t3 join t2 on t3.food=t2.food
    group by 1,2
) least
where r=1
```

Assuming you want something out of t1 would be like:

```
select t1.name, least.type from (
    select t3.userid, t2.type, count(*) as eaten,
        row_number() over(partition by t3.userid order by count(t3.food) asc) AS r
    from t3 join t2 on t3.food=t2.food
    group by 1,2
) least
join t1 on t1.userid=least.userid
where least.r=1
```

Here is a way to do it without the window function. This way uses a self join on the counts of types eaten to identify the least eaten and filter the other more frequently eaten foods (added t1 assuming you want some field out of there):

```
with type_counts as (
    select t3.userid, t2.type, count(*) as eaten,
    from t3 join t2 on t3.food=t2.food
    group by 1,2
)
select t1.username, tc.userid, tc.type
from type_counts tc
inner join (select userid, min(eaten) as eaten from type_counts group by 1) mintc
    on tc.userid=mintc.userid and tc.eaten=mintc.eaten
inner join t1 on t1.userid=tc.userid
```

This version will include ties for least eaten.